# Countdown timer working stop on chrome extensions.

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I think that I will build chrome extensions to count down. 
In case of the present code, if popup.html is closed, processing will be completed compulsorily. 
In this case, is it better to write setInterval to background.js? 
Moreover, I want you to teach whether what I should do concrete.

**background.js**

```
var num = window.localStorage.setItem("minite_num", 20);
default_count = num*60;

function count_start() {
    count = default_count;
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        path: {
            "19": "img/icon_count19.png",
            "38": "img/icon_count38.png"
        }
    });
}

function count_down() {
count--;
if (count <= 0) {
    page_change();
    count_stop();
    }
}
```

**popup.js**

```
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
var num = bg.num;
var start_btn = document.count_timer.start_btn;
var count_time = document.getElementById("counter");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    load();
    start_btn.addEventListener('click', start_display);
});

function timer_reset() {
    timerID = 0;
}

function count_format(num) {
    var tm,ts;
    tm = Math.floor(num / 60); //分
    ts = num % 60; //秒
    if (ts < 10) ts = "0" + ts;
    return tm + ":" + ts;
}

function load(){
    display_num = bg.count_format(bg.default_count);
    bg.timer_reset();

    start_btn.disabled = false;
    count_time.innerHTML = display_num;
}

function start_display() {
    start_btn.disabled = true;
    bg.count_start();
    timerID = setInterval(function() {bg.count_down();count_time.innerHTML = bg.count;}, 1000);
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<form name="count_timer" class="count_timer">
    <div id="counter" class="counter"></div>
    <input type="button" name="start_btn" value="START">
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Explain exactly what is not working with the code?

Comment: @ZigMandel his interval (see `timerID`) lives in the popup context, that gets destroyed.

Comment: yes, interval goes in background, not popup. use messaging to communicate beteen them

Comment: @ZigMandel Once it will close popup, countdown will return to stop origin. 
Should setInterval be moved to background? 
In that case, what should I do for carrying out count_time.innerHTML by the popup side?

Comment: please read more about messaging, and yes I said before that you need to do so in the background. popup only lives while it shows.

Comment: ok i understood better your situation and posted an answer.

Comment: I am sorry to have checked what you were already told. 
The obtained reply is checked.

Answer (score 0):

use chrome storage / localStorage to remember your target time.
Use an interval from the popup to update your calculations. First time, the popup needs to read from storage and determine where the countdown is at.
Nothing needs to be done from background, unless you want to separate logic (as in MVC), then maybe do all storage stuff from background, and ask for it with messaging.
I have a published open-source chrome extension (plus for trello) with a count(up) timer feature that does something similar.

Comment: Thank you for teaching separation of logic, and the directions for localStorage. 
The method of acquiring the data which processed by background from popup, and making it innerHTML wanted to know. 
I am sorry to be incomprehensible. 

I check your extensions by reference.
Thanks.